# Rotate icon with css on mouse hover

Tags: html, css, icons, rotatetransform

After checking out I implemented below code but the effect is not happening, don't know where its lacking..

```
<style>


            .rotate {
                -webkit-transition: -webkit-transform 0.4s ease-in-out;
                -moz-transition: -moz-transform 0.4s ease-in-out;
                -o-transition: -o-transform 0.4s ease-in-out;
                -ms-transition: -ms-transform 0.4s ease-in-out;
                transition: transform 0.4s ease-in-out;
                cursor:pointer;
}
            .rotate:hover { 
            color:#afafaf;
            -webkit-transform: rotateZ(360deg);
    -moz-transform: rotateZ(360deg);
     -ms-transform: rotateZ(360deg);
      -o-transform: rotateZ(360deg);
    transform: rotateZ(360deg);

            }
            </style>
```

HTML

```
<div class="col-lg-6 col-md-6 col-sm-12">
                <h2 align="center"><a href="abc.php" class="rotate"> <icon class="icon icon-rocket icon-2x "> </icon> </a> <br />
                Build your Resume </h2>
            </div>
```

Edit: changed the rotate CLASS from icon to parent

Comment: what browser are you testing this in? If it's IE8 or older, no chance. Also what doctype are you declaring?

Comment: The `rotate` class should be to the parent container or `h2` tag but not to the `icon` element.

Comment: @Mr_green : already tested with that ..

Comment: @atjoshi check this [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/Fsjf4/)

Comment: <!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd">
  <html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">

Testing in firefox and chrome

Comment: @LOTUSMS its working with the <img /> but not with icon

Comment: It seem to be working in Chrome: http://jsfiddle.net/borglinm/eVRFx/

Comment: Mr_Green i want to rotate just the icon .. else its working fine as I mentioned above

Comment: I dont believe the rotate transition works with HTML strict. Change the doctype to HTML 5 and retest

Answer (score 9):

It will work with `animation`:

```
<div class="col-lg-6 col-md-6 col-sm-12">
    <h2 align="center"><a href="abc.php" class="rotate"> <icon class="icon icon-rocket icon-2x "> </icon> </a> <br />
        Build your Resume </h2>
</div>
```

CSS:

```
.rotate {
    cursor:pointer;
}

.rotate:hover { 
    color:#afafaf;
    -moz-animation: spin .4s 1 linear;
    -o-animation: spin .4s 1 linear;
    -webkit-animation: spin .4s 1 linear;
    animation: spin .4s 1 linear;
}

@-webkit-keyframes spin {
    0% { -webkit-transform: rotate(0deg); }
    100% { -webkit-transform: rotate(359deg); }
}

@-moz-keyframes spin {
    0% { -moz-transform: rotate(0deg); }
    100% { -moz-transform: rotate(359deg); }
}

@-o-keyframes spin {
    0% { -o-transform: rotate(0deg); }
    100% { -o-transform: rotate(359deg); }
}

@-ms-keyframes spin {
    0% { -ms-transform: rotate(0deg); }
    100% { -ms-transform: rotate(359deg); }
}

@keyframes spin {
    0% { transform: rotate(0deg); }
    100% { transform: rotate(359deg); }
}
```